# Is there a curl/wget option that prevents saving files in case of http errors?

Tags: scripting, curl, wget

I want to download a lot of urls in a script but I do not want to save the ones that lead to HTTP errors.

As far as I can tell from the man pages, neither `curl` or `wget` provide such functionality.
Does anyone know about another downloader who does?

Comment: As far as I can see Oct is the only person who actually read the question and answered it.  Everyone else gave you techniques that would *never ever* download anything, or they said to roll your own.  Shouldn't you accept the only *real* answer you were given?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One liner I just setup for this very purpose:

(works only with a single file, might be useful for others)

```
A=$$; ( wget -q "http://foo.com/pipo.txt" -O $A.d && mv $A.d pipo.txt ) || (rm $A.d; echo "Removing temp file")
```

This will attempt to download the file from the remote Host. If there is an Error, the file is not kept. In all other cases, it's kept and renamed.

Comment: Did you mean to say "if there is *an* error, the file is not kept"?  Otherwise you did the opposite of what was requested.

Answer (score 32):

I think the `-f` option to `curl` does what you want:

> `-f`, `--fail`
>
> (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors. This is mostly done to  better
>             enable  scripts  etc  to  better deal with failed attempts. In normal cases when an HTTP
>             server fails to deliver a document, it returns an HTML document stating so (which  often
>             also  describes  why  and  more).  This  flag will prevent curl from outputting that and
>             return error 22. [...]

However, if the response was actually a 301 or 302 redirect, that still gets saved, even if its destination would result in an error:

```
$ curl -fO http://google.com/aoeu
$ cat aoeu
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/aoeu">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

To follow the redirect to its dead end, also give the `-L` option:

> `-L`, `--location`
>
> (HTTP/HTTPS)  If  the  server  reports  that the requested page has moved to a different
>                 location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this  option  will
>                 make  curl redo the request on the new place. [...]

Comment: no, it's only related to verbosity of errors.
once used, errors do are not reported (but saved as usual)

thanks anyway

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted (`curl -fO {URL}`). It does not save a file on a `404`. Thank you

Comment: @hypercrypt Your comment confused me until I realized what was going on. Edited in an important caveat.

Comment: `-fLO` are my new favourite curl flags now :) `curl -fLO http://google.com/aoeu` => `curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found`

Comment: IMO, this should be the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome solution, but keep in mind it is technically not fool-proof. For example, a URL might return `200` but the file content on the server is empty, etc. In many cases it is a good idea to "test" the retrieved file for either a given string (e.g. `grep`) or non-zero file size (e.g. to ensure that the downloaded file is not empty).

Answer (score 3):

Ancient thread.. landed here looking for a solution... ended up writing some shell code to do it.

```
if [ `curl -s -w "%{http_code}" --compress -o /tmp/something \
      http://example.com/my/url/` = "200" ]; then 
  echo "yay"; cp /tmp/something /path/to/destination/filename
fi
```

This will download output to a tmp file, and create/overwrite output file only if status was a 200. My usecase is slightly different.. in my case the output takes > 10 seconds to generate... and I did not want the destination file to remain blank for that duration.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** I am aware that this is an older question, but I believe I have found a better solution for those using `wget` than any of the above answers provide.

```sh
wget -q $URL 2>/dev/null
```

Will save the target file to the local directory if and only if the HTTP status code is within the 200 range (Ok).

Additionally, if you wanted to do something like print out an error whenever the request was met with an error, you could check the [wget exit code](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) for non-zero values like so:

```sh
wget -q $URL 2>/dev/null
if [ $? != 0]; then
    echo "There was an error!"
fi
```

I hope this is helpful to someone out there facing the same issues I was.

**Update:**
I just put this into a more script-able form for my own project, and thought I'd share:

```sh
function dl {
    pushd . > /dev/null
    cd $(dirname $1)
    wget -q $BASE_URL/$1 2> /dev/null
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        echo ">> ERROR could not download file \"$1\"" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
    popd > /dev/null
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: it is critical that you not call `wget` using the `-O` flag. `-O` will always create a new file, regardless of the request status, although it usually won't put anything in the file on error.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround to propose, it does download the file but it also removes it if its size is 0 (which happens if a 404 occurs).

```
wget -O <filename> <url/to/file>
if [[ (du <filename> | cut -f 1) == 0 ]]; then
    rm <filename>;
fi;
```

It works for zsh but you can adapt it for other shells.

But it only saves it in first place if you provide the `-O` option

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can create a temporal rotational file:

```
wget http://example.net/myfile.json -O myfile.json.tmp -t 3 -q && mv list.json.tmp list.json
```

The previous command will always download the file "myfile.json.tmp" however only when the wget exit status is equal to 0 the file is rotated as "myfile.json".

This solution will prevent to overwrite the final file when a [network failure occurs](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html).

The advantage of this method is that in case that something is wrong you can inspect the temporal file and see what error message is returned.

The "-t" parameter attempt to download the file several times in case of error.

The "-q" is the quiet mode and it's important to use with cron because cron will report any output of wget.

The "-O" is the output file path and name.

Remember that for Cron schedules it's very important to provide always the full path for all the files and in this case for the "wget" program it self as well.

Answer (score -3):

You can download the file without saving using `"-O -"` option as

```
wget -O - http://jagor.srce.hr/
```

You can get mor information at http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Advanced-Usage

Comment: This is *not* what the OP asked for.  He asked for a way to not download files *if there is an error*.  Your answer doesn't download *anything, ever*.